# Place a Comparison Operator within Select Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Im very new to SQL and I wanted to know if I am able to place a comparison operator in the select portion

ex

```
Select
(value> value1, "True","False") as Comparison
From Table
```

Comment: If there is something that works within the Select statement then that would work too.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? SQL Server/Mysql/Postgres?

Comment: Oracle SQL @shahkalpesh

Comment: If the answer by @Saeed helped you, accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your joins in the comments are ok you could try it like this:

```sql
Select 
--  ... ... ...
    CASE WHEN s.TOT_AMT > 0 THEN 'Credit' ELSE 'Debit' END "CREDIT_DEBIT", 
--  ... ... ...
FROM 
    sum_by_alloc_id s 
INNER JOIN 
    last_by_alloc_id l ON(l.ORGNTNG_CASH_ID = s.ORGNTNG_CASH_ID)
INNER JOIN 
    first_by_alloc_id f ON(f.ORGNTNG_CASH_ID = s.ORGNTNG_CASH_ID) 
INNER JOIN 
    first_row_not_only_suspense fns ON(fns.ORGNTNG_CASH_ID = s.ORGNTNG_CASH_ID)
LEFT JOIN 
    agrmnt_dtls a ON(a.AGRMNT_NBR = l.DERIVED_AGRMNT_NBR)
```

Comment: I tried this method and added it to the overall code. Unfortunately it did not like it and I got the error message " Missing Keyword"

Comment: Just posted correction . Sorry there was END keyword missing. My mistake.

Comment: Ignore this comment, I realized that i didnt end the case statement its running now. Thanks for the tip on this! I will report back if/when i get results.

Comment: I can confirm this is working for me so thank you so very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

**For SQL Server:** There is two options

**`IIF` Function:**

```sql
Select IIF(value> value1, 'True','False') as Comparison From Table
```

**`CASE` Function:**

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN value> value1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END as Comparison From Table
```

**For Oracle:** You can use `CASE` Function:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN value> value1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END as Comparison From Table
```

Comment: So when I tried this it gave me an error stating that the right parenthesis is missing when there isnt.

Comment: sqlserver needs single quotes around string constants. And also supports 'case'

Answer (score 0):

If you try to query in that way it will only return the Boolean values as you are trying to compare between two values. As the "True" and "False" are just string it will print only "True" and "False"
You can see in the below image for a reference
[image]

Comment: So for this, I have a column of values and I want to have it return whether or not the value is greater than zero in a a different column

(s.TOT_AMT> 0, "Credit","Debit")

Comment: Can you please give me more clarification on this question?

Comment: Basically want it to look like this 

Select (s.TOT_AMT > 0, 'Credit', 'Debit') as "Credit/Debit"
FROM sum_by_alloc_id s
    JOIN last_by_alloc_id l
    ON l.ORGNTNG_CASH_ID = s.ORGNTNG_CASH_ID
    JOIN first_by_alloc_id f
    ON f.ORGNTNG_CASH_ID = s.ORGNTNG_CASH_ID
    JOIN first_row_not_only_suspense fns
    ON fns.ORGNTNG_CASH_ID = s.ORGNTNG_CASH_ID
    LEFT JOIN agrmnt_dtls a
    ON a.AGRMNT_NBR = l.DERIVED_AGRMNT_NBR

Comment: The column in which you are writing the comparison operator wouldn't effect the other columns as long as you don't write it in the where clause.